# dscacheutil shows an empty cache?

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard

Is it normal for dscacheutil to return an (almost) empty cache? I tried the same -cachedump command on 10.5.8 and I got a list of internal and external hosts as I'd expected to have seen.

The 1.5~ million cache misses for gethostbyname was after firing up a FileMaker database that opens in sub 30s on 10.5.8 but takes over 5 minutes in 10.6.6.

**dscacheutil -statistics**

```
Overall Statistics:
  Average Call Time     - 0.001025
  Cache Hits            - 1533905
  Cache Misses          - 3063347
  Total External Calls  - 1539214

Statistics by procedure:

         Procedure   Cache Hits   Cache Misses   External Calls
------------------   ----------   ------------   --------------
          getpwnam          542            129              671
          getpwuid         6242            510             6752
          getgrnam          106            175              281
          getgrgid            6             32               38
     getservbyname      1527001            661               63
          getfsent            0              0              193
      getnetbyaddr            0             35               35
     gethostbyname            8        1530311             1950
     gethostbyaddr            0            861              861
gethostbyname_service            0              0          1528369
```

**sudo dscacheutil -cachedump -entries**

```
DirectoryService Cache Overview:
AAAA Queries  - Disabled (link-local IPv6 addresses)
Cache Size    - 8

Entry count by category:
    Group    - 3
    Service  - 1
    User     - 4

Cache entries (ordered as stored in the cache):

  Category         Best Before         Last Access      Hits    Refs       TTL    Neg  DS Node
----------  ------------------  ------------------  --------  ------  --------  -----  ---------
      User   01/26/11 11:08:31   01/26/11 10:45:38       124       1      3600         /Local/Default
                 Key: pw_name:dale
                 Key: pw_uid:502

     Group   01/26/11 11:09:28   01/26/11 10:09:28         0       1      3600         /Local/Default
                 Key: gr_uuid:ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000009
                 Key: gr_gid:9
                 Key: gr_name:procmod

     Group   01/26/11 11:09:28   01/26/11 10:09:28         0       1      3600         /Local/Default
                 Key: gr_name:procview
                 Key: gr_uuid:ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000008
                 Key: gr_gid:8

   Service   01/26/11 11:09:45   01/26/11 10:44:38         1       1      3600         /BSD/local
                 Key: s_name:ipp
                 Key: s_name:ipp s_proto:udp
                 Key: s_port:631 s_proto:udp

      User   01/26/11 11:09:46   01/26/11 10:43:34        21       1      3600         /Local/Default
                 Key: pw_name:spotlight
                 Key: pw_name:_spotlight
                 Key: pw_uid:89

     Group   01/26/11 11:43:53   01/26/11 10:43:53         0       1      3600         /Local/Default
                 Key: gr_name:tty
                 Key: gr_gid:4
                 Key: gr_uuid:ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000004

      User   01/26/11 11:44:38   01/26/11 10:44:38         0       1      3600         /Local/Default
                 Key: pw_name:root
                 Key: pw_uid:0

      User   01/26/11 11:44:38   01/26/11 10:44:39         1       1      3600         /Local/Default
                 Key: pw_gecos:Unprivileged User
                 Key: pw_name:nobody
                 Key: pw_uid:-2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the machines I have here it looks like a normal profile

Machine 1

```
     Procedure   Cache Hits   Cache Misses   External Calls
------------------   ----------   ------------   --------------
          getpwnam         1714             46             1760
          getpwuid         5746             94             5840
          getgrnam          129             55              184
          getgrgid            7             24               31
     getservbyname        34238             72               98
     getservbyport            0             10               10
    getprotobyname           71              8               79
  getprotobynumber           15              0               15
          getfsent            0              0               11
         getnetent            0              0                1
      getnetbyname            0              2                2
      getnetbyaddr            1              4                5
     gethostbyname            4          34789               26
     gethostbyaddr            0            366              366
gethostbyname_service            0              0            34767
       _flushcache            0              0                5
```

Machine 2

```
Statistics by procedure:

             Procedure   Cache Hits   Cache Misses   External Calls
    ------------------   ----------   ------------   --------------
              getpwnam        33929           1530            35459
              getpwuid        20118           1171            21289
              getgrnam         2649           1314             3963
              getgrgid          118             83              201
         getservbyname         1543            642             1599
        getprotobyname           42             70              112
      getprotobynumber           45             33               78
              getfsent            0              0               19
             getnetent            0              0                6
          getnetbyname            8              4               12
          getnetbyaddr            0             34               34
         gethostbyname            0           9194             8021
         gethostbyaddr            0            156              156
    gethostbyname_service            0              0             1173
```

Comment: What version of OSX are you on? and does `sudo dscacheutil -cachedump -entries` give you any Host records?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.6.6 on both machines and no host records either, but that's due to Mac OS X 10.6.x separating the DNS cache from the general DS database, for that now you should check the internal DB of mDNSResponder, you can get a full list of the cache hosts there by running `sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder`, all the info will be dumped into /var/log/system.log